# Transforming number groups

Tags: python, sequence

I want the program to take blocks of numbers from a numeric sequence (which I enter, could be 1000 numbers).
Each two numbers equals one number.

For example:

1. the numbers 8,9 in a row equal 1.
2. Then numbers 4,8 equal 6, it goes on.
3. Each number from 0-9 paired with another number from 0-9 has its own value.

> say the sequence goes like this `927284629146`
>   I want the program to pick the two numbers in groups like this
>   (`92`)(`72`)(`84`)(`62`)(`91`)(`46`)
>   and return `871236` (depending on what value each group makes)

I'm sorry if this might sound confusing.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm afraid it *does* sound confusing. How does "4,8 equal 6"? Perhaps you could clearly state some example input and output for your program, as well as what you have tried so far (Stack Overflow is not a code writing service).

Comment: yes it is really really confusing. what have you tried? post your code.

Comment: Input 

a = 98
b = 89
c = 72
special_value = int(raw_input('Enter value: ')) 
while True:
    if special_value == a: 
        print 7
    elif special_value == b:
        print 6
    elif special_value == c:
        print 4

Comment: the values won't mean anything mathematically, its just what value is given for a two digit number

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so from what you are saying, it seems like you have a

*f: Z_10 x Z_10  -> Z_10*

A good way to represent this function is to use a dictionary data structure to hold the values. Then iterate over the sequence (most likely a list), and take each element and it's successor in the sequence and use it to index into the dictionary. I think it is a bit elementary to code. Judging by the question, you might be a beginner. Show me what you have got, and I will point you in the right directions (in the comments)